# StaleObjectStateException when read from Spring Data repository

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the next Java code:

```
public Role reproduceIssue(String code) {
    repository.findOneByCode(code);
    roleChangedService.onRoleChanged(code);
    return null;
}
```

The code first reads a role by code from repository (in one transaction, marked as read only) and then calls another method `RoleChangedService#onRoleChanged` (in another transaction). The method is like this:

```
@Transactional
public void onRoleChanged(String code) {
    Role resource = roleRepository.findOneAndLockByCode(code);
    resource.setName(null);
    roleRepository.saveAndFlush(resource);
}
```

`RoleRepository#findOneAndLockByCode` is annotated with `@Lock(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)`.

Every time I send 2 parallel HTTP requests to call the `reproduceIssue` method in parallel, I get `org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)` on the `RoleRepository#findOneAndLockByCode` method call.

I wonder, how is the exception possible, given that I use the lock on this method?

The reproduction project (as well as the shell scripts that simulate the parallel call) is available [here](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/tree/master/spring-transaction-sandbox).